# Save .xlsm as xlsx to destination defined in cell + add date

Tags: vba, excel, xlsx, xlsm

Quick question, I'm trying to save a file with the destination being defined in cell A1 (because the file can be located on different servers, depending on the user), plus the date it was saved. Could you please help me out?
The VBA that I currently have is the following:

```
Sub Macro2()

    'turn off pop-ups
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Range("A15").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        Range("a1") & "CSI_ERE_1" & Today() & ".xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use Vegard answer to avoid messages implement this ....Application.DisplayAlerts = False .......Vegard code ......... Application.DisplayAlerts = True ........ if that works mark his answer as solved if not let us know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had great results omitting `FileFormat` when saving from XLSM to XLSX.

Try:

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= Range("A1").Value & "CSI_ERE_1" & Format(Date(), "dd.mm.yy") & ".xlsx"`

And if that does not work:

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= Range("A1").Value & "CSI_ERE_1" & Format(Date(), "dd.mm.yy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51`

Using numerical fileformat has better backwards compatibility, and for some reason unknown to me, seems to be easier to use in general than the name constants.

List of fileformats and their numerical values: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I get a Run-time error '1004': This extension can not be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the file name text box or select a different file type by changing the Save as type.

Comment: Upvote just use Date. Today is in sheet. Date is function in VBA.

Comment: Indeed, if `Today()` does not work (it doesn't for me), use `Date()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vegard and @Lance! It almost fully works, however, when I use date, it gives me an error (method SaveAs of object '_workbook' failed: 
' ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("A1").Value & "CSI_ERE_1" & Date & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51 '

If I use it without date, it works fine 
'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("A1").Value & "CSI_ERE_1.xlsx", FileFormat:=51'
What could be the problem? It would be really nice to add the date to the file (for back-up reasons)

Comment: I am guessing that's because `Date()` returns with a value containing an unexpected character. Try solving it with a `NumberFormat`, ref. again updated answer. You can edit the format to be whatever you like, within the limits of what is allowed in a filename.

Comment: that is strange it works for me .. second variant of what Vegard wrote and surround it by display alerts switches... even when I open completely new workbook not saved and run macro that saves it.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks again guys!